# Azure Spatial Anchors / Unity World Anchors lose position

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, azure-spatial-anchors

I am working on a simple unity app testing azure spatial anchors on the HoloLens. I started from this example (https://github.com/Azure/azure-spatial-anchors-samples) and changed it a little bit to create several anchors.

In some test sessions I experienced that the anchored objects lost their position suddenly and where moved about 10 meters or more.

As I unterstand HoloLens and mixed reality the camera position is tracked by kind of visual odometry or rather SLAM algorithms so it is normal that the pose of the device drifts over the time and so will the anchors do. But I did not expect such a huge shift. 
Furthermore I expected the anchors to get back in places in the moment the features in the neighborhood of the anchors are visible again for the devices camera. But this is not always the case. Sometimes the anchors get back at their original position when the features are visible again, but sometimes this does not change anything about the wrong positions.

This is the code:

```
using Microsoft.Azure.SpatialAnchors;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.XR.WSA;
using UnityEngine.XR.WSA.Input;
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;
using UnityEditor;

public class AzureSpatialAnchorsScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The sphere prefab.
    /// </summary>
    public GameObject spherePrefab;

    /// <summary>
    /// Set this string to the Spatial Anchors account id provided in the Spatial Anchors resource.
    /// </summary>
    protected string SpatialAnchorsAccountId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

    /// <summary>
    /// Set this string to the Spatial Anchors account key provided in the Spatial Anchors resource.
    /// </summary>
    protected string SpatialAnchorsAccountKey = "yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy";

    /// <summary>
    /// Our queue of actions that will be executed on the main thread.
    /// </summary>
    private readonly Queue<Action> dispatchQueue = new Queue<Action>();

    /// <summary>
    /// Use the recognizer to detect air taps.
    /// </summary>
    private GestureRecognizer recognizer;

    protected CloudSpatialAnchorSession cloudSpatialAnchorSession;

    /// <summary>
    /// The CloudSpatialAnchor that we either 1) placed and are saving or 2) just located.
    /// </summary>
    protected CloudSpatialAnchor currentCloudAnchor;

    /// <summary>
    /// True if we are creating + saving an anchor
    /// </summary>
    protected bool tapExecuted = false;

    /// <summary>
    /// The IDs of the CloudSpatialAnchor that were saved. Use it to find the CloudSpatialAnchors
    /// </summary>
    protected Dictionary<string, GameObject> cloudSpatialAnchorIdsObjects = new Dictionary<string, GameObject> { };

    protected IList<string> anchorIds = new List<string>();

    /// <summary>
    /// The sphere rendered to show the position of the CloudSpatialAnchor.
    /// </summary>
    protected Material sphereMaterial;

    /// <summary>
    /// Indicate if we are ready to save an anchor. We can save an anchor when value is greater than 1.
    /// </summary>
    protected float recommendedForCreate = 0;

    private string pathName;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Application.SetStackTraceLogType(LogType.Log, StackTraceLogType.None);

        recognizer = new GestureRecognizer();

        recognizer.StartCapturingGestures();

        recognizer.SetRecognizableGestures(GestureSettings.Tap);

        recognizer.Tapped += HandleTap;

        InitializeSession();

        string FileName = "ids.txt";
        pathName = Path.Combine(Application.persistentDataPath, FileName);
        getIds();

        if (anchorIds.Count > 0)
        {
            CreateWatcher(anchorIds.ToArray());
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        lock (dispatchQueue)
        {
            if (dispatchQueue.Count > 0)
            {
                dispatchQueue.Dequeue()();
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Queues the specified <see cref="Action"/> on update.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="updateAction">The update action.</param>
    protected void QueueOnUpdate(Action updateAction)
    {
        lock (dispatchQueue)
        {
            dispatchQueue.Enqueue(updateAction);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Cleans up objects.
    /// </summary>
    public void CleanupObjects()
    {
        if (cloudSpatialAnchorIdsObjects != null)
        {
            cloudSpatialAnchorIdsObjects = new Dictionary<string, GameObject>();
        }

        if (sphereMaterial != null)
        {
            Destroy(sphereMaterial);
            sphereMaterial = null;
        }

        //currentCloudAnchor = null;
    }   

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new CloudSpatialAnchorSession.
    /// </summary>
    void InitializeSession()
    {
        Debug.Log("ASA Info: Initializing a CloudSpatialAnchorSession.");

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(SpatialAnchorsAccountId))
        {
            Debug.LogError("No account id set.");
            return;
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(SpatialAnchorsAccountKey))
        {
            Debug.LogError("No account key set.");
            return;
        }

        cloudSpatialAnchorSession = new CloudSpatialAnchorSession();

        cloudSpatialAnchorSession.Configuration.AccountId = SpatialAnchorsAccountId.Trim();
        cloudSpatialAnchorSession.Configuration.AccountKey = SpatialAnchorsAccountKey.Trim();

        cloudSpatialAnchorSession.LogLevel = SessionLogLevel.All;

        cloudSpatialAnchorSession.Error += CloudSpatialAnchorSession_Error;
        cloudSpatialAnchorSession.OnLogDebug += CloudSpatialAnchorSession_OnLogDebug;
        cloudSpatialAnchorSession.SessionUpdated += CloudSpatialAnchorSession_SessionUpdated;
        cloudSpatialAnchorSession.AnchorLocated += CloudSpatialAnchorSession_AnchorLocated;
        cloudSpatialAnchorSession.LocateAnchorsCompleted += CloudSpatialAnchorSession_LocateAnchorsCompleted;

        cloudSpatialAnchorSession.Start();

        Debug.Log("ASA Info: Session was initialized.");
    }

    void CreateWatcher(string[] cloudSpatialAnchorIds)
    {
        Debug.Log("ASA Info: We will look for placeded anchors.");

        // Create a Watcher to look for the anchor we created.
        AnchorLocateCriteria criteria = new AnchorLocateCriteria();
        criteria.Identifiers = cloudSpatialAnchorIds;
        cloudSpatialAnchorSession.CreateWatcher(criteria);

        Debug.Log("ASA Info: Watcher created. Number of active watchers: " + cloudSpatialAnchorSession.GetActiveWatchers().Count);
    }

    private void CloudSpatialAnchorSession_Error(object sender, SessionErrorEventArgs args)
    {
        Debug.LogError("ASA Error: " + args.ErrorMessage);
    }

    private void CloudSpatialAnchorSession_OnLogDebug(object sender, OnLogDebugEventArgs args)
    {
        Debug.Log("ASA Log: " + args.Message);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("ASA Log: " + args.Message);
    }

    private void CloudSpatialAnchorSession_SessionUpdated(object sender, SessionUpdatedEventArgs args)
    {
        Debug.Log("ASA Log: recommendedForCreate: " + args.Status.RecommendedForCreateProgress);
        recommendedForCreate = args.Status.RecommendedForCreateProgress;
    }

    private void CloudSpatialAnchorSession_AnchorLocated(object sender, AnchorLocatedEventArgs args)
    {
        switch (args.Status)
        {
            case LocateAnchorStatus.Located:
                Debug.Log("ASA Info: Anchor located! Identifier: " + args.Identifier);
                QueueOnUpdate(() =>
                {
                    // Create a green sphere.
                    GameObject spatialAnchorObj = GameObject.Instantiate(spherePrefab, Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
                    spatialAnchorObj.AddComponent<WorldAnchor>();
                    sphereMaterial = spatialAnchorObj.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material;
                    sphereMaterial.color = Color.green;

                    // Get the WorldAnchor from the CloudSpatialAnchor and use it to position the sphere.
                    spatialAnchorObj.GetComponent<UnityEngine.XR.WSA.WorldAnchor>().SetNativeSpatialAnchorPtr(args.Anchor.LocalAnchor);

                    cloudSpatialAnchorIdsObjects.Add(args.Anchor.Identifier, spatialAnchorObj);

                    Debug.Log("Detected Pos: " + spatialAnchorObj.GetComponent<UnityEngine.XR.WSA.WorldAnchor>().transform.position.ToString("F4"));
                    Debug.Log("Detected Rot: " + spatialAnchorObj.GetComponent<UnityEngine.XR.WSA.WorldAnchor>().transform.rotation.ToString("F4"));

                    tapExecuted = false;
                });
                break;
            case LocateAnchorStatus.AlreadyTracked:
                Debug.Log("ASA Info: Anchor already tracked. Identifier: " + args.Identifier);
                break;
            case LocateAnchorStatus.NotLocated:
                Debug.Log("ASA Info: Anchor not located. Identifier: " + args.Identifier);
                break;
            case LocateAnchorStatus.NotLocatedAnchorDoesNotExist:
                Debug.LogError("ASA Error: Anchor not located does not exist. Identifier: " + args.Identifier);
                break;
        }
    }

    private void CloudSpatialAnchorSession_LocateAnchorsCompleted(object sender, LocateAnchorsCompletedEventArgs args)
    {
        Debug.Log("ASA Info: Locate anchors completed. Watcher identifier: " + args.Watcher.Identifier);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Called by GestureRecognizer when a tap is detected.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="eventArgs">The tap.</param>    
    public void HandleTap(TappedEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        if (tapExecuted)
        {
            return;
        }
        tapExecuted = true;

        Debug.Log("ASA Info: We will create a new anchor.");

        //// Clean up any anchors that have been placed.
        //CleanupObjects();

        // Construct a Ray using forward direction of the HoloLens.
        Ray GazeRay = new Ray(eventArgs.headPose.position, eventArgs.headPose.forward);

        // Raycast to get the hit point in the real world.
        RaycastHit hitInfo;
        Physics.Raycast(GazeRay, out hitInfo, float.MaxValue);

        this.CreateAndSaveSphere(hitInfo.point);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a sphere at the hit point, and then saves a CloudSpatialAnchor there.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="hitPoint">The hit point.</param>
    protected virtual void CreateAndSaveSphere(Vector3 hitPoint)
    {
        // Create a white sphere.
        GameObject spatialAnchorObj = GameObject.Instantiate(spherePrefab, hitPoint, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
        spatialAnchorObj.AddComponent<WorldAnchor>();
        sphereMaterial = spatialAnchorObj.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material;
        sphereMaterial.color = Color.white;
        Debug.Log("ASA Info: Created a local anchor.");

        // Create the CloudSpatialAnchor.
        currentCloudAnchor = new CloudSpatialAnchor();

        // Set the LocalAnchor property of the CloudSpatialAnchor to the WorldAnchor component of our white sphere.
        WorldAnchor worldAnchor = spatialAnchorObj.GetComponent<WorldAnchor>();
        if (worldAnchor == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("ASA Error: Couldn't get the local anchor pointer.");
        }

        // Save the CloudSpatialAnchor to the cloud.
        currentCloudAnchor.LocalAnchor = worldAnchor.GetNativeSpatialAnchorPtr();

        //cloudAnchor.AppProperties[@"x"] = @"frame";
        //cloudAnchor.AppProperties[@"label"] = @"my latest picture";

        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            // Wait for enough data about the environment.
            while (recommendedForCreate < 1.0F)
            {
                await Task.Delay(330);
            }

            bool success = false;
            try
            {
                QueueOnUpdate(() =>
                {
                    // We are about to save the CloudSpatialAnchor to the Azure Spatial Anchors, turn it yellow.
                    sphereMaterial.color = Color.yellow;
                });

                await cloudSpatialAnchorSession.CreateAnchorAsync(currentCloudAnchor);
                success = currentCloudAnchor != null;

                if (success)
                {
                    // Record the identifier to locate.
                    string cloudAnchorId = currentCloudAnchor.Identifier;

                    QueueOnUpdate(() =>
                    {
                        // Turn the sphere blue.
                        sphereMaterial.color = Color.blue;
                    });

                    Debug.Log("ASA Info: Saved anchor to Azure Spatial Anchors! Identifier: " + cloudAnchorId);
                    //Debug.Log("Created " + cloudAnchorId + " at pos: " + worldAnchor.transform.position);
                    //Debug.Log("Created " + cloudAnchorId + "at rot: " + worldAnchor.transform.rotation);

                    anchorIds.Add(cloudAnchorId);
                    cloudSpatialAnchorIdsObjects.Add(cloudAnchorId, spatialAnchorObj);

                    WriteIds();
                }
                else
                {
                    sphereMaterial.color = Color.red;
                    Debug.LogError("ASA Error: Failed to save, but no exception was thrown.");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                QueueOnUpdate(() =>
                {
                    sphereMaterial.color = Color.red;
                });
                Debug.LogError("ASA Error: " + ex.Message);
            }

            // Allow the user to tap again to clear state and look for the anchor.
            tapExecuted = false;
        });
    }

    void WriteIds()
    {
        try
        {
            string fileContent = ""
                //= ReadString();
                ;

            foreach (string id in anchorIds)
            {
                fileContent += id + Environment.NewLine;
            }

            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(new FileStream(pathName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write)))
            {
                writer.Write(fileContent);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debug.LogError(e);
        }
    }

    void getIds()
    {
        try
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(pathName);

            string line;
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                anchorIds.Add(line);
            }

            reader.Close();
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            Debug.LogWarning("No AnchorId file found");
        }
    }
}
```

Is something wrong with the way the anchors are created or is this normal behavior?

Answer (score 0):

It is not surprising behavior that sometimes the anchors lose their position and it could be the case that some of the anchors are relocalized after tracking is recovered, but not all of them. It could be helpful to add a script to the object you create for the anchor that shows the tracking state of the anchor attached to it. Here is a sample:-

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.XR.WSA;

public class ShowTrackingState : MonoBehavior
{
    WorldAnchor worldAnchor = null;
    Material renderMaterial = null;
    bool isTracking = false;
    void Start()
    {
        renderMaterial = gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().material;
    }

    void OnDestroy()
    {
        if (renderMaterial != null)
        {
            Destroy(renderMaterial);
        }
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (worldAnchor == null)
        {
            worldAnchor = gameObject.GetComponent<worldAnchor>();
        }

        if (worldAnchor == null)
        {
            isTracking = false;
        }
        else
        {
            isTracking = worldAnchor.isLocated;
        }

        renderMaterial.color = isTracking ? Color.red : Color.green;
    }
}
```

Also, a gentle reminder, it is a common mistake to forget to hide one's account id and key when posting questions on forums; but it is not secure so you might want to remove that part from your code snippet in the question :-)